# Analysis- show fixed point

Tags: analysis

[image]

I learnt about lipschitz functions and know the theorem about them having fixed points, Im trying to use that concept here but I'm not succeeding. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Consider the space of irrational numbers.

Comment: @i707107 still isnt helping me :(

Comment: Let $X$ be the set of all positive irrational numbers. Consider a metric on $X$ that makes $(X,d)$ complete.